# Set SVN bugtraq propset properties for all current and new repository directories and file commits?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-propset

We've got a SubVersion repository containing existing projects, but we frequently add new projects and internal-use tools to it as well.

I've set the `bugtraq` prop-set properties on files and directories (including the root svn repository folder), but they aren't automatically added for new project check-ins / commits.

Is there any way that I can set up the repository (or the clients) so that all files and directories (without exception) in the repository have these `bugtraq` properties assigned?

We use TortoiseSVN (if it's relevant!)